# result null when find by id in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have installed on localhost:

- nodejs v9.2.1
- npm v5.5.1
- mongodb v3.4
- package

  mongodb v3.0.4
  mongoose v5.0.11

I connect to database and get document by id

My code

```
var MongoDB = require("mongodb");
var mongo = MongoDB.MongoClient;
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", function(err, client){
    if (err) throw err;

    var db = client.db("my_database");
    db.collection("accounts").findOne({email : "email@example.com"}, function(err, doc){
        console.log(doc);
    });
});
```

Result:

```
{
    _id : 5ab464aba4697729b8003653,
    email : 'email@example.com'
}
```

So, I replace condition to `{_id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}`, I receive `null`

I write other code:

```
var MongoDB = require("mongodb");
var mongo = MongoDB.MongoClient;
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database');
var accSchame = mongoose.Schema({
    email : {type : String}
});

var Accounts = mongoose.model('accounts', accSchame);
Accounts.findById('5ab465a8a4697729b8003655', function(err, doc){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(doc);
});
```

I receive `null` too.
Can someone tell me why?

Comment: pass id  like this `{ _id : '5ab465a8a4697729b8003655' }`

Comment: use only mongoose module and try

Comment: @kgangadhar : I edited and result `null` too.